# CSV import into MYSQL problems

Tags: mysql, csv

I am trying to import CSV files into MYSQL using the Import Wizard.

There are two problems:

1. MYSQL will not read the dates.  I have changed my Windows date format to `YYYY-MM-DD`, so that I can format the CSV cells as dates with the right format.  But SQL only wants to import them as TXT.  If I instruct SQL that the data is DATETIME, it rejects the import.
2. Varchar cells in the CSV are being imported as TXT.  I cannot get MYSQL to assign them Varchar values.

I would prefer to identify the problem on the CSV side than scripting a data change on the other end.

What's really wrecking my head is that I was able to do this in the past.

Comment: Please add an example of the CSV and the table structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I am brand new to the site and have not figured out how to add attachments.  Sorry for being such a noob

Comment: No attachments needed. Just add a csv line to the question. You can format it with th code button in the question editor.

Comment: For a `DATETIME` the correct format would be `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`. If you just have the date, use a `DATE` field. For the second question - I'm not sure I understand; do you not have control over the field type, like in the first question?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your support.

I figured it out.

Windows 10 regional settings places a date format of DDMMYYYY on all Microsoft Office packages.  Even if you place a date format of YYYYMMDD on the CSV, when you import it into MYSQL using the Import Wizard - it defaults to the regional date setting.  So MYSQL will not import it as DATETIME.

Its a very irritating problem - easily fixed by changing your Operating System date format.